# JSTL form relative path

Tags: java, struts, jstl, tomcat7

I have tomcat installed on server and available at server.com/app/. It means that the tomcat's root application is hosted at that url.

Now I am trying to deploy new application (old.war) and the server deploys it at server.com/app/old/. Untill now that's fine.

The problems start when I create some form at the page with such definition:

```
<html:form name="LoginForm" type="some.form" action="/LoginFormAction" method="post">...
```

and at the output I receive action's value "/old/LoginFormAction.do". That's wrong value because it misses "app" at the begining. I tried different action's values, for example

```
<html:form name="LoginForm" type="some.form" action="/app/old/LoginFormAction" method="post">...
<html:form name="LoginForm" type="some.form" action="/app/LoginFormAction" method="post">...
```

but it still adds the "/old" prefix in action's value.
How can I solve that problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STR-768) Struts 1 doesn't support relative paths in form's action attribute. So there is no way to solve it. Even with hacks like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103213/can-struts-1-1-post-to-a-relative-path).

Answer (score 0):

If the tomcat's root is app , then it won't be available for you , (think of it as '/' maps to 'app/') , you should use relative path , try

```
`action="LoginFormAction"` and it should work fine.
```

Comment: I tried this one. It still converts the action's value to /old/LoginFormAction